# Женская фамилия - Руда. Как склоняется? Попадежно

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Женская фамилия – Руда. Как просклонять правильно?

Answer (score 3):

**Фамилия (мужская и женская) склоняется по образцу 1-го склонения**

В самом первом походе на Казань, предпринятом в 1467 г. Иваном III, в его войско входил отряд казаков под началом атамана **Ивана Руды.**

Склонение  https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Ruda/skloneniye.html

Происхождение  [http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/Руда](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: а если фамилия как краткая форма прилагательного - «Рудая»

Comment: Это форма полного прилагательного, такая фамилия тоже склоняется  https://www.analizfamilii.ru/Rudiy/skloneniye.html?familiya=%D0%F3%E4%FB%E9